# HNibernate 1 to Many Relationship Fluent NHiberate using only the Foreign Key Id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

I'm wanting to have a 1 to many relationship in NHibernate where the Child table only has access to it's parentsId. Or the foreign key in the DB.

I've tried the following setup:

```
public class ParentTable
{
    public ParentTable()
    {
        _childRecords = new List<ChildTable>();
    }

    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }

    private IList<ChildTable> _childRecords;

    public virtual IEnumerable<ChildTable> ChildRecords
    {
        get { return _childRecords; }
    }

    public void AddChildTable(string value)
    {
        _childRecords.Add(new ChildTable{ StringField = value });
    }
}

public class ChildTable
{

    public virtual int ChildTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual string StringField { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ParentTableMap : ClassMap<ParentTable>
{
    public ParentTableMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.ParentId);

        HasMany(x => x.ChildRecords)
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId").Cascade.All()
            .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
    }
}

public class ChildTableMap : ClassMap<ChildTable>
{
    public ChildTableMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.ChildTableId);

        Map(x => x.StringField);
        Map(x => x.ParentId).Not.Nullable();
    }

}
```

The following test fails as it's trying to insert 0 into the ParentId column?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void SaveOrUpdate_ParentWithChildren_WillCreateParentWithChildRecordsHavingMatchingParentId()
    {

        int id;
        using (var sessionForInsert = SessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trx = sessionForInsert.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //Assign
                var parent = new ParentTable();
                parent.AddChildTable("Testing");
                parent.AddChildTable("Testing2");
                sessionForInsert.SaveOrUpdate(parent); // Fails here with DB constraint error 
                id = parent.ParentId;
            }
        }

        using (var sessionForSelect = SessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //Action
            var result = sessionForSelect.Get<ParentTable>(id);
            Assert.AreEqual(id, result.ParentId);
            Assert.AreEqual(id, result.ChildRecords.First().ParentId);
            Assert.AreEqual(id, result.ChildRecords.Last().ParentId);
        }

    }
}
```

This is what it's trying to do:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO ChildTable (StringField, ParentId) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar,@p1 int',@p0='Testing;,@p1=0
```

I realise I could set-up a reference to the Parent Class in the Child Class. However I'd like to avoid this if at all possible, due to circular references and the problems that will cause when serializing and de-serializing these classes.

Has anyone successfully set-up and 1 to many relationship like the above?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need to:

- Make the `ParentId` on `ChildTable` nullable, or
- Change your id generators to something NHibernate can generate.

The second option is nice. Switch to Guid.Comb for your id's. There's a restriction on what object relational mappers can do. Specifically, it is recommended to let NHibernate generate the id's instead of the database. I think this (long) blog post explains it in detail: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/02/nh210-generators-behavior-explained.html.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to insert a parent and its children in one operation. To do this, NHibernate wants to insert the child records with a null ParentId then update ParentId after the parent record is inserted. This foreign key constraint causes this to fail.

The best solution is to map the relationship from child to parent. You don't have to publicly expose the parent, you could just expose its ParentId as int? if desired.

If that's unacceptable, you should be able to accomplish this by changing the order of operations. First, I would require the ParentId in ChildTable's constructor. Then change the operation order in the test to get it to pass.

```
public class ChildTable
{
    public ChildTable(int parentId) { ParentId = parentId; }
    public virtual int ChildTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual string StringField { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; private set; }
}

using (var trx = sessionForInsert.BeginTransaction())
{
    //Assign
    var parent = new ParentTable();
    sessionForInsert.Save(parent);
    sessionForInsert.Flush(); // may not be needed
    parent.AddChildTable("Testing");
    parent.AddChildTable("Testing2");
    trx.Commit();
    id = parent.ParentId;
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class ChildTable
{
    private ParentTable _parent;

    public ChildTable(Parent parent) { _parent = parent; }

    public virtual int ChildTableId { get; set; }
    public virtual string StringField { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentId 
    {
        get { return _parent == null : null ? _parent.ParentId; }
    }
}

public class ChildTableMap : ClassMap<ChildTable>
{
    public ChildTableMap()
    {
        Not.LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.ChildTableId);

        Map(x => x.StringField);
        // From memory, I probably have this syntax wrong...
        References(Reveal.Property<ParentTable>("Parent"), "ParentTableId")
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, When you say "The best solution is to map the relationship from child to parent. You don't have to publicly expose the parent, you could just expose its ParentId as int? if desired." Can you explain how I would do that?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work in the end. doing the Reveal on a References doesn't appear to be documented anywhere... In the end I decided to have a public property on ChildTable to ParentTable and this is set when adding a Child Record to the List.